# Putting a new item in to the calendar overwrites the other item inside

Tags: wpf, vb.net, scheduled-tasks, wpf-controls, drag

Hello can someone please tell me what could be the problem in my calendar. So let me explain whats happening. So first im trying to make a scheduler application and im using a WPF scheduler in VB, so to begin with, the tab of a calendar needs to display 3 items (Subject, Professor Name, Courses) so what i need to do is to choose a room first and then drag a subject name from the listbox (like this [Sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKnAJ.png)) and then next i need to drag a professors name ([Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeQhZ.png)) and then heres where the problems starts

So it already displays two items (Subject and Professor) now i need to drag an item from Course listbox, but the problem is whenever I put a course to the tab of a calendar, it becomes like this  [instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ28L.png)

So the goal here is to show 3 dragged items but instead, it only shows 2 and the course is overwriting the name of the subject. Please help me, thank you! If you want to see the whole codes, heres the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWKisPr9qDh54B4EMdwWJbY3KFgi_xfc/view?usp=sharing

Heres the code of where you can drag the items

```
 'Dragging Data to Calendar
Sub Add_list_item(ByVal list As String)
    Delay.Delay(1)
    Dim count = 0
    For Each item As CalendarItem In Calendar1.GetSelectedItems()
        count += 1

        If count > 1 Then
            Return
        Else
            Dim get_item_end_time As DateTime = item.EndDate.AddHours(2)
            get_item_end_time = get_item_end_time.AddMinutes(30)
            Dim item_start_time = item.StartDate
            Dim item_end_time = get_item_end_time
            Dim item_tooltip = item.StartDate.ToString()
            Dim start_time = item.StartDate.ToString("HH:mm tt")
            Dim end_time = item.EndDate.ToString("HH:mm tt")
            Dim dat_start As Date = item_tooltip
            Dim ci As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
            Dim dtfi As DateTimeFormatInfo = ci.DateTimeFormat
            dtfi.AbbreviatedDayNames = {"Sun", "1", "2", "3", "4",
                                         "5", "6"}
            Dim output_start As String = String.Format(ci, "{0:ddd}", dat_start.AddDays(0))

            Dim item_text = CStr(item.Text)
            Dim parts As String() = item_text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                           StringSplitOptions.None)

            Dim get_item_total_hours = (item.EndDate - item.StartDate).TotalHours
            Dim get_start_time As DateTime
            Dim get_end_time As DateTime

            If get_item_total_hours = 1 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddMinutes(-30)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddMinutes(30)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 1.5 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-1)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(1)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 2 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-1).AddMinutes(-30)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(30)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 2.5 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-2)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(2)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 3 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-2).AddMinutes(-30)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(2).AddMinutes(30)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 3.5 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-3)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(3)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 4 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-3).AddMinutes(-30)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(3).AddMinutes(30)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 4.5 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-4)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(4)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 5 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-4).AddMinutes(-30)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(4).AddMinutes(30)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 5.5 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-5)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(5)
            ElseIf get_item_total_hours = 6 Then
                get_start_time = item.StartDate.AddHours(-5).AddMinutes(-30)
                get_end_time = item.EndDate.AddHours(5).AddMinutes(30)
            End If

            If (ListBox1_Instructor.Items.Contains(list) = True) Then
                Call Check_if_instructor(list)
            End If

            If parts.Count >= 3 Then
                If (instructor_name = True) Then

                    Call Get_instructor_code(instructor_gender + list)
                    Call Get_course_name(corSec_id)
                    Call checkInstructorSchedule(start_time, end_time, output_start, instructor_id)

                    If (instructor_name = True) Then
                        If instructor_gender = "Male" Then
                            instructor_gender = "Mr. "
                        Else
                            instructor_gender = "Ms. "
                        End If

                        If item.Text <> "" Then
                            item.Text = parts(0) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + instructor_gender + list
                            item.ApplyColor(Color.RoyalBlue)
                        End If
                        instructor_name = False
                    End If

                Else
                    item.ApplyColor(Color.RoyalBlue)
                    item.Text = list + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + parts(2) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine
                End If
            ElseIf parts.Count = 1 Then
                If (instructor_name = True) Then

                    Call Get_instructor_code(instructor_gender + list)
                    Call Get_course_name(corSec_id)
                    Call checkInstructorSchedule(start_time, end_time, output_start, instructor_id)

                    If (instructor_name = True) Then
                        If instructor_gender = "Male" Then
                            instructor_gender = "Mr. "
                        Else
                            instructor_gender = "Ms. "
                        End If

                        If item.Text <> "" Then
                            item.Text = parts(0) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + instructor_gender + list
                            item.ApplyColor(Color.RoyalBlue)
                        End If

                        instructor_name = False
                    End If
                Else
                    item.ApplyColor(Color.RoyalBlue)
                    item.Text = list + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + parts(parts.Count - 1) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine
                End If
            End If
            Calendar1.Invalidate(item)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Josh Filamor I have not tried this but instead of dragging items from the listbox Suggestion Try Clicking the item and sent it to the correct cell in a DataGridView OR into the cell in the Calendar

Comment: Okay sir, ill try that. I'll update you as soon as possible